# Prettify code on click of button - Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-code-prettify

Am using google code prettify for my javascript code.
I have a form which has a submit button, on filling up of the form and clicking on submit buttom; generates some code snippet.

problem : Same function is called on onload and onclick which generates the code.
The code generated through onload is prettified but am unable to see the same result on click of submit button (though generates the correct code).

code:

```
function onStartLoadObject(){
.....some code here...
var node =  '<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">' + '<code class="scroll">'+    
                            '&lt;script type="text/javascript" src="js/vSpinner.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;<br>'+
                            '&lt;script&gt;<br>'+
                                '// Our Javascript will go here.<br>'+
                                'var container = "vSpinnerContainer"<br>'+
                                'var source = "images/myproducts_{n}.jpg"<br>'+
                                'var numberOfFrames = 36<br>'+ '</code>' + '</pre>';
....some code here....
}
```

Please note that, onload my 'pre' tag looks like: `<pre class="prettyprint lang-html prettyprinted" style="">` and onclick of submit button `<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">`

Comment: Is your onsubmit handler stopping the form from submitting and reloading the page?